# Как же всё-таки правильно?

Tags: сокращения

Речь идет о ЕДИНИЦАХ СИСТЕМЫ СИ. Наверное, каждый знает, что после обозначений единиц Системы СИ и их производных точка не ставится, в отличие от обычных сокращений. В данном случае речь идет о секундах: например 5 с/сек (без точки) или же 5 с./сек.(с точкой). Вопреки этому правилу ГРАМОТА.РУ рекомендует точку: "точки после этих сокращений ставятся: _мин., ч., с." Как же правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Грамота.ру говорит не о системе СИ, а о простых сокращениях в текстах, тогда как  в научной литературе с использованием системы СИ используются сокращения без точек, вот в таблице:
http://www.dpva.info/Guide/GuideUnitsAlphabets/GuideUnitsAlphabets/AccelerationConvertion/1 м/с² 1 см/с² = galileo = gal

http://daniyar.mmm-tasty.ru/entries/88387                                      Точки не ставятся после сокращений стандартных единиц измерения (СИ): «150 м, 16 кг, 300 л». Точки также не ставятся после сокращений «млн» и «млрд» (но после «тыс.» — ставятся): «1 млн», но «23 тыс.». После сокращений единиц измерения, не являющихся стандартными, точки ставятся: «30 шт., 12 000 руб.»

Comment: А что у Вас за измерение? Не скорость нагрева? Тогда С-Цельсия, с большой буквы и без всяких точек:1.170*С, 1,5*С/сек, 10 сек
2. 190*С, 0,4*С/сек, 30 сек
3. 230*С, 0,4*С/сек, 10 сек

Comment: И ещё градусы-кружочек вверху:Скорость нагревания/охлаждения 5.0°С/сек и 4.5°С/сек!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Все эти правила я знаю. Наверное, сама себя загнала в языковые дебри.Сначала.  Очень часто в прессе встречаю разности в написании, н-р:Я пробегаю за 10 с/с.//сек/сек. это расстояние. Я бы написала "10 с". Ведь мы же пишем "скорость ветра 20 м/с?

Comment: 10 с/с.//сек/сек. - это уже не система СИ,не является стандартным сокращением,это по аналогии с гг.-года, но гг.-есть общепринятое сокращение, а сек/сек нет, надо писать полностью.

Comment: Это,  наверно,  вообще  опечатка.

Comment: Опечатка точка или "сек"?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: ГОСТ 8.417-2002]

Согласно ГОСТ 8.417-2002 секунды - единица СИ величины время, пишется с маленькой буквы без точки "с"

Comment: Ольга, зачем эти все таблицы? Да еще в виде картинок, без указания источника. Вполне достаточно сформулировать ваше утверждение - и дать ссылку на источник.